# Repeat installation issue when running vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Every time I run vscode, vscode repeats the installation as shown in the picture below. How do I solve this?

[image]

Comment: did you try fresh installation ? (uninstall, download, install)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are clicking on the .exe file of vs code. Search the app and click on the app

[image]

Comment: have you looked in the VSCode directory, it is an `.exe` too, `code.exe`